# install mysql and java and my program in one click

Tags: java, mysql, silent-installer

I have develop an application with java
this application is use mysql database
i want to install this applications in one click:
1- check if mysql is already installed but with specific port
2- install mysql as silent install in specific location
3- mysql server must use another port that i will define
4- check if java is installed
5- install java
6- install my application in specific location
7- think you for helping me.

Comment: you should research about this topic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_%28computer_programs%29. Looks like something that you want to do with several machines... sometimes, it's just easier to have a pre-installed image and just use that

Answer (score 0):

Think you i use mini-server
http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/MiniServer/MiniServer_%20MySQL%205.0.67%20Portable/
it's a portable verion
i will find how to change the port